# telepresence: error: connector.Connect: the traffic manager gRPC API timed out

Tags: kubernetes, telepresence

when I using this command in macOS Monteney 12 to connect to kubernetes(1.23) cluster:

```
telepresence connect
```

show error like this:

```
telepresence: error: connector.Connect: the traffic manager gRPC API timed out.  The current timeout 15s can be configured as "timeouts.trafficManagerAPI" in "/Users/example/Library/Application Support/telepresence/config.yml"

See logs for details (28 errors found): "/Users/example/Library/Logs/telepresence/connector.log"
If you think you have encountered a bug, please run `telepresence gather-logs` and attach the telepresence_logs.zip to your github issue or create a new one: https://github.com/telepresenceio/telepresence/issues/new?template=Bug_report.md .
```

I have tried to instatll `socat` in the server host. Still did not fixed this problem. The telepresence version is:

```
➜  ~ telepresence version
Client: v2.5.8 (api v3)
Root Daemon: v2.5.8 (api v3)
User Daemon: v2.5.8 (api v3)
```

anyone facing the same issue in the newest version of telepresence? This is the detail output:

```
2022-05-08 14:42:32.7014 info    connector/session : Connected to context context-reddwarf (https://106.14.183.131:6443)
2022-05-08 14:42:32.7648 info    connector/session : Connecting to traffic manager...
2022-05-08 14:42:32.7648 error   connector/session : unable to get APIKey: GetAPIKey: not logged in
2022-05-08 14:42:32.8477 info    connector/session : Existing Traffic Manager 2.5.8 not owned by cli or does not need upgrade, will not modify
2022-05-08 14:42:33.0033 error   connector/session : Error with k8sPortForwardDialer dial: unable to upgrade connection: pod not found ("traffic-manager-5cb99c9fd6-cvh26_ambassador")
2022-05-08 14:42:34.1164 error   connector/session : Error with k8sPortForwardDialer dial: unable to upgrade connection: pod not found ("traffic-manager-5cb99c9fd6-cvh26_ambassador")
2022-05-08 14:42:35.4853 error   connector/session : Error with k8sPortForwardDialer dial: unable to upgrade connection: pod not found ("traffic-manager-5cb99c9fd6-cvh26_ambassador")
2022-05-08 14:42:37.7611 error   connector/session : Error with k8sPortForwardDialer dial: unable to upgrade connection: pod not found ("traffic-manager-5cb99c9fd6-cvh26_ambassador")
2022-05-08 14:42:42.0067 error   connector/session : Error with k8sPortForwardDialer dial: unable to upgrade connection: pod not found ("traffic-manager-5cb99c9fd6-cvh26_ambassador")
2022-05-08 14:42:47.9749 error   connector/session : Unable to connect to TrafficManager: the traffic manager gRPC API timed out.  The current timeout 15s can be configured as "timeouts.trafficManagerAPI" in "/Users/example/Library/Application Support/telepresence/config.yml"
```

I checked traffic-manager pod and found it was in the namespace `ambassador`. the I have already tried this command with kubernetes namespace:

```
telepresence connect -n ambassador
```

I also tried to tweak the timeout in `config.yml`:

```
timeouts:
  trafficManagerAPI: 90
  trafficManagerConnect: 90
```

still did not fixed this problem.

Comment: I'm currently facing the same issue with telepresence `Client: v2.4.2 (api v3)`

Comment: try to reinstsall the server side component with the right version, or remove the server side and make the telepresence install it automatically. @ezekiel

Comment: Having similar issues with:

`Client: v2.7.1 (api v3)`
`Root Daemon: v2.7.1 (api v3)`
`User Daemon: v2.7.1 (api v3)`

Answer (score 0):

Today I am facing the similiar issue `Telepresence connect: error: connector.Connect: the port-forward connection to the traffic manager timed out`, fisrt I check the log `/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/Library/Logs/telepresence/connector.log` and found out the error like this:

```
2023-03-06 02:36:33.5346 error   connector/session : Error with k8sPortForwardDialer dial: unable to upgrade connection: pod not found ("traffic-manager-56489c7cb7-pgdx8_ambassador")
2023-03-06 02:36:36.2675 error   connector/session : Error with k8sPortForwardDialer dial: unable to upgrade connection: pod not found ("traffic-manager-56489c7cb7-pgdx8_ambassador")
2023-03-06 02:36:40.4036 error   connector/session : Error with k8sPortForwardDialer dial: unable to upgrade connection: pod not found ("traffic-manager-56489c7cb7-pgdx8_ambassador")
2023-03-06 02:36:48.1923 error   connector/session : Error with k8sPortForwardDialer dial: unable to upgrade connection: pod not found ("traffic-manager-56489c7cb7-pgdx8_ambassador")
2023-03-06 02:36:58.3995 error   connector/session : Error with k8sPortForwardDialer dial: unable to upgrade connection: pod not found ("traffic-manager-56489c7cb7-pgdx8_ambassador")
```

then I found this pod was terminating for a long time, then delete the pod like this:

```
kubectl delete pod traffic-manager-56489c7cb7-pgdx8 -n ambassador --grace-period=0 --force
```

rerun the connect command like this:

```
➜  telepresence sudo telepresence connect
Connected to context context-reddwarf (https://10.124.23.121:6443)
```

problem solved. this is the newest version info of telepresence:

```
➜  telepresence telepresence version
Client         : v2.11.1
Root Daemon    : v2.11.1
User Daemon    : v2.11.1
Traffic Manager: v2.11.1
```

hope this could help others.